# How easy create a lot of the same chart. Excel

Tags: excel

I have to create 120 charts like this:

[image]

From data like this:

[image]

How can i do it faster then create new chart foreach tabel.

In the future i can again do this chart for other data. How should i do that to don't do it again but only put new data for charts.

Comment: With VBA, but your question is too broad that we can't answer it.

Comment: To do "only put new data for charts", just save as a new file then replace the data with the new one will do.